# Filter flattened Google Sheets table and replace values

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm generating Table 2 out of Table 1
[image]

with following formula:

```
={flatten({A3:A,A3:A}),arrayformula(flatten({if(A3:A<>"",B$2,),if(A3:A<>"",C$2,)})),flatten({B3:C})}
```

How can convert the 1s to `true`and 0s to `false` and set a filter to show only the rows with `true` in the same formula?

So, the desired outcome would be:
[image]

[Link to Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OFvKt-hn2ML8Gd2GN1XA5a2rD1y-xOxkQaRmCoc0WXk/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `QUERY`:

```
=QUERY({flatten({A3:A,A3:A}),arrayformula(flatten({if(A3:A<>"",B$2,),if(A3:A<>"",C$2,)})),ARRAYFORMULA(flatten({B3:C=1}))},"WHERE Col3=TRUE")
```

[image]